# Correct way to run a select query from blades in laravel 5 using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

What is the Correct Way to retrieve a column value based on certain select filter on a Model variable availed by `compact` method inside the blade. (Larevl 5)
I read that Its a bad practice to query database staright from views, and hence i followed the convention to avail the required data with `compact` method to view

However, In a scenario where I need to query another table based on certain column value returned in foreach loop inside a blade from first table, I am unable to figure out correct Approach

Example: I have two Models `User` & `Group`

Schema  `User` Table

```
id,name,email,group_id
```

Scheme Group Table
`id`,`groupname`

Here is the UserController -> compact method

```
$users = \App\User::all(array('id','name','email','group_id'));
$groups = \App\Group::all(array('id','group_name'));
return view('user.index',  compact('users','groups'));
```

Here how the blade needs them

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
      <tr>
            <th>{{$user->id}}</th>
            <th>{{$user->name}}</th>
            <th>{{$user->email}}</th>
            <th>
              <!-- Here i need to run something like 
select group_name from group where id = $user->id -->
{{$groups->where('id','=',$user->group_id) }}

            </th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

I know this returns an array , and I'have two questions here

1. How to get the value for `group_name` column from the Group Model based on group.`id` = `$user->id` in a foreach loop
2. Since Its a bad practice to query db from blade, how would I avail the values from a model by passing data via compact from controller to blade, when the where clause parameter's are not yet known.

**Edit 1:**

I modified the last group query as

```
 <th>@if($groups->where('id','=',$user->group_id))
                  @foreach($groups as $group)
      {{$group->group_name}}            
                  @endforeach
                @endif
</th>
```

And I was able to get the result, however this again isn't a correct approach , so question remain unanswered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `User` model

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}
```

In `Group` model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

In your controller

```
$users = \App\User::with('group')->get();
return view('user.index',  compact('users'));
```

Now in your view you can do

```
$user->group->name;
```

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to if you are to get the maximum out of Eloquent :)

Comment: update   `$users = \App\User::with('group')->get();`    using \ before the Model Class so that it dont throw not found error

Comment: may be i missing something, running `$user->group->name` throws error 
`trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: It means that either your user object or group object is null. Check the `$user` and see if it exists or you could use Laravels `firstOrFail` or `findOrFail`. If `$user` exists above should work if users always have a group. If not then you need to first check for the existence of group. you could use `dd()` function to see what was returned.

Answer (score 5):

I appreciate the fact that you know "It's bad practice to query from view".
Why don't you use join.

```
DB::table('users')->join('groups', 'users.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')->get();
```

Then pass the result to your view and loop through it.
Here you will have each user data associated with his group data.